# My form jumps upward when it comes to extra-small screen size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0epz.png)

Here is my index.html code

```
<body style="background: url(assets/img/back.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;  height:auto; margin-top:0px;">
    <div class="container" >

        <div class="row" style="margin-top:40%; margin-left:-2em;">
            <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-5 center">

                <form name="form1" action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal " role="form">

                      <select class="form-control" id="sel1"  >
                        <option>עיר מגורים</option>
                        <option>תל אביב">תל אביב</option>
                        <option>דן כללי">גוש דן כלל</option>
                        <option>השרון">השרון</option>
                        <option>השפלה">השפלה</option>
                        <option>חיפה">חיפה</option>
                        <option>ירושלים">ירושלים</option>
                        <option>באר שבע והסביבה">באר שבע והסביבה</option>
                        <option>אשדוד, אשקלון והסביבה">אשדוד, אשקלון והסביבה</option>
                        <option>השפלה">השפלה</option>
                        <option>הגליל התחתון">הגליל התחתון</option>
                        <option>אחר </option>
                      </select>

                     <select class="form-control" id="sel1"  >
                        <option>רמת אנגלית </option>
                        <option>מתחיל </option>
                        <option>בינוני </option>
                        <option>גבוהה </option>
                     </select>

                     <select class="form-control" id="sel1" >
                        <option> מטרת לימוד </option>
                        <option> רמה אישית </option>
                        <option> לעסק </option>
                        <option> לראיון עבודה </option>
                        <option> נסיעה לחו"ל </option>
                        <option> למבחן אמי"ר\פסיכומטרי </option>
                        <option> לימודים </option>
                     </select>


                     <select class="form-control" id="sel1" >
                        <option> הכי חשוב לי בקורס </option>
                        <option> סביבת לימודים נעימה </option>
                        <option> מקום עם וותק וניסיון </option>
                        <option> גמישות וזמינות </option>
                        <option> מורים מקצועיים </option>
                        <option> מעטפת שלמה ללימוד אנגלית </option>
                        <option> הכל חשוב לי </option>
                     </select>


                     <select class="form-control" id="sel1" >
                        <option> תקציב </option>
                        <option> 1000 עד </option>
                        <option> 1000-2000 ש"ח </option>
                        <option> 2000-3000 ש"ח </option>
                        <option> 3000-6000 ש"ח </option>
                        <option> 6000 מעל </option>
                     </select>

                     <input name= "name" type="text" placeholder="שם" required>
                     <br>
                     <input name= "phone" type="text" placeholder="כתובת מייל שלך" required>
                     <br>
                     <input type="submit" value="!מצא לי קורס">

                </form> 
            </div>
            <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
            <div class="vedio col-xs-11 col-sm-8 center col-md-6  col-lg-5" >
                <video   controls >לחץ לצפייה בטבלת השוואה של קורסים שונים
                  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                  Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
            <!-- ---------------------------------------Video-------------------------------------------- -->
        </div>
            <!-- --------------------------------------1st ROW ENDS----------------------------------------------- -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" style="padding-top:2em;">
                    <p > <a href="http://liron6822.wix.com/english-help#!-/c1hsn">לחץ לצפייה בטבלת השוואה של קורסים שונים </a></p>
                </div>
            <!-- --------------------------------------2nd ROW ENDS----------------------------------------------- -->
            </div>
        <!-- ----------------------------------------Container ENDS------------------------------------------------- -->    
    </div>
</body>
```

It works fine in case of large screen size and also in medium screen size, now. What I want it to remain there as it is in case of large screen size.

Comment: Please post your CSS also and if you can make a snippet it would be much better

Comment: Here is the Css of this page
input, select{
 width:100%;
 margin:1% auto;
 padding:2% 1%;
 font-size:1.3em;
 border-radius:2px;
 border:1px solid ;
}
input[type="submit"] {
background-color:#337ab7;
width:50%;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}
.video {
    position: relative;
    
}